# Translate problem about

Tags: magento2, translate

How to Translate about this code please?

```
->addSuccessMessage(__('Your #' . $incrementId . ' has been submited.'));
```

I tried Your #%1 xxxx but not working?

anyone can help,

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use this one

```
->addSuccessMessage(__('Your # . %1 has been submitted.', $incrementId));
```

> put SPACE after #

Comment: not working, it is showing " syntax error, unexpected '%'

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This :-**

```
->addSuccessMessage(__('Your # %1 has been submited.',$incrementId));
```

Comment: Working or not ??

Comment: yes, it is working, thank you

Comment: If answer is useful than approve answer.. thank you☺️